# Dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 - cannot boot into Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10, rst

I have an ASUS laptop with Windows 10 on it, boot mode is UEFI.

I have disabled Fast Startup, Fast Boot, Secure Boot before installing Ubuntu 20.04 (followed the guide here: https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/).

On first startup, the system showed Grub Recovery Mode, I had to type some Grub commands (set prefix, set root, insmod...) to get it to boot.

Second startup, the system booted directly into Windows and I haven't found a way to boot into Ubuntu again (it booted into Windows even when I choose ubuntu from the UEFI boot menu).

I tried booting from the boot USB, installing Boot-Repair but there was no "Recommended repair" option. The report says "The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would not act on the boot". You can see the report here: https://pastebin.com/3YjYwXXy

Ubuntu is installed on /dev/nvme0n1p5. I also tried fixing grub manually but got an error when trying to mount that partition.

(I have dual boot installed on a few other machines, they all used legacy BIOS mode. This UEFI thing is a pain)

Please help. Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**
I tried mounting the EFI System Partition, the ubuntu folder existed but looked like there was some error:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/mnt/efi/EFI$ ls
ls: cannot access 'ubuntu': Input/output error
Boot  Microsoft  ubuntu
```

Last few lines of dmesg:

```
[ 1174.092156] FAT-fs (nvme0n1p1): error, corrupted directory (invalid entries)
[ 1174.092164] FAT-fs (nvme0n1p1): Filesystem has been set read-only
[ 1176.296661] FAT-fs (nvme0n1p1): error, corrupted directory (invalid entries)
[ 1177.390047] FAT-fs (nvme0n1p1): error, corrupted directory (invalid entries)
[ 1181.030055] FAT-fs (nvme0n1p1): error, corrupted directory (invalid entries)
```

The comp has Intel RST with Optane installed and after some research I found out that maybe Ubuntu won't work well with it. Could that be the cause of the problem and should I disable it?

Thanks.

**Update 2:** I tried disabling RST following this guide: https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-installation-on-computers-with-intel-r-rst-enabled/15347, but was unsuccessful (had to go through the recovery steps but the bcdboot command failed). Guess I should stay with the VM option for a little longer.

Comment: Maybe something happened when you installed ubuntu..if you still have the .iso file you can install again easily

Comment: I have tried reinstalling a few times but no luck. Guess disabling RST is the only option left

Comment: Update: I tried disabling RST following this guide: https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-installation-on-computers-with-intel-r-rst-enabled/15347, but was unsuccessful (had to go through the recovery steps but the bcdboot command failed). Guess I should stay with the VM option for a little longer.